# vuejs2: accessing nested javascript objects inside components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am building a front end admin form using quasar based on several axios calls to the server to get various aspects of the form.  (all of this stuff is put in the `data(){}` component):

```
 formDefinition: {
      main_info : [
           field1, field2, field3
      ],
      second_section : [
           field4, field5, field6
      ]
 }
```

This is for laying out the form visually.

Then via another couple calls, I build the list of fields and the attributes of each field, for example

```
 formChildren: {
      field1 : {
           datatype:"datetime"
           editable:true
           label:"Archive On"
           required:false
     },
     field2 : {...}
 }
```

In the template, i nest two v-fors:

```
 <div class="sectionContainer" v-for="(elements, section) in formDefinition">
      <h3>{{section}}</h3>
      <ul>
           <li v-for="(fieldName, index) in elements" :key="index">
               <p>item: {{index}}  :: {{formChildren[fieldName]}} ::  typeof: {{ typeof formChildren[fieldName]}}</p>
 <!-- etc -->
```

(that echoes out things like this:)

```
 item: 0 :: { "value": "testfilm", "subtype": "slug", "datatype": "string", "editable": true, "min_length": "3", "max_length": "1024", "required": true, "index": "unique", "label": "slug" } :: typeof: object
```

The gist of the problem is I'm trying to find the best way to access nested members of formChildren using the fieldName either in the template or in a method. `formChildren[fieldName]` works fine. `formChildren[fieldName].datatype` returns "Cannot read property 'datatype' of undefined", even though echoing out `{{ typeof formChildren[fieldName] }}` returns "object".

Kinda thinking I just need to rework all of the object building logic but I can't think of a way that avoids *some* kind of nesting. maybe each fieldName needs its own object? Seems crazy.

N.B.: I'm told by a dialog that similarly titled questions are often downvoted or closed, but this is the most succinct way to title it that I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is fetched from the server, it is loaded asynchronously.

When the template **first** renders, then, the `formChildren` data is probably not there yet.

When it first renders, `{{ typeof formChildren[fieldName] }}` returns `"undefined"`, but this first render is overwritten so fast you don't even get to see it.

For the `"Cannot read property 'datatype' of undefined"` error to appear, though, you just need to request the undefined property once and it will throw an exception, no matter if in just a couple of ms it becomes defined.

**Solution:** add a `v-if` so it won't render if not loaded:

```
<p v-if="formChildren[fieldName]"> item: {{index}}  :: {{formChildren[fieldName]}} ... </p>
```